# Apps script for Gmail - search for exact subject

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I get every day multiple automatic emails. One has the subject 'Daily Report' and one has the subject 'Daily Report details'. This is the script I was using, but once the emails started coming without chronological order, I sometimes catch the wrong one.

```
 var threads = GmailApp.search('Daily Report') //search gmail with the given query(partial name using * as a wildcard to find anything in the current subject name).
 var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
```

Is there a way to tell the search that I want the mail with exact subject 'Daily Report' and not the one with 'Daily Report Details'?

Thanks

Comment: As pointed on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String,Integer,Integer)), the query field is "the search query, as you would type it into Gmail", so I don't think you can select the correct one only by the search method. Otherwise, you can look on the GmailThread[] that you collect to compare the [GmailMessage.getSubject()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getSubject()) with the sujbect you're looking for.

Comment: I think you could add `-Details` to just get the Daily Report without details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Pierre-Marie Richard and @Cooper mentioned, you can use the built-in Gmail search functions. Here are a list of the [Gmail Search Functions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), like @Cooper mentioned you may be best using something like:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"Daily Report"-Details')
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
```

The quotes (**""**) work as an exact match and the minus ('**-**') is to exclude a word. 
If that still doesn't work let me know and I will look further into it.

Good Luck :)