# Extract the exact subjects and update the google sheets using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have found a below mentioned apps script to get the subject name of the emails from the particular label and update the google sheets.

```
function getSubjects() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Test");
var threads = label.getThreads();
var row = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages=threads[i].getMessages();

for (var m=0; m < messages.length; m++) {  
sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(messages[m].getSubject());
row++;
  }
 }
};
```

On daily basis, I will receive more than 100 emails with the same subject lines with small modifications. So, I need to get in the google sheets only the emails that have a subject line which includes the word "Pending".

I am hoping someone can help me make this example work.

Comment: So your code currently gets the subject, what do you mean by "exact" subject? Is your code not returning what you're expecting? Show us some example outputs.

Comment: For example: Task1_08_13_2019_Pending, Task1_08_13_2019_Completed,Task2_08_13_2019_Pending. Here I have mentioned three subjects of the emails. Per day, I'll receive more than 100 status emails. I need to fetch only the emails which have pending status.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apps script for Gmail - search for exact subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174943/apps-script-for-gmail-search-for-exact-subject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind. I have figured it out. Below is the updated code which is working as expected.

```
function getSubject() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject: Successfully Completed is:Test/2019_08');
  var row = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
  for (var m=0; m < messages.length; m++) {  
  sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(messages[m].getSubject());
  row++;
      }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the [Gmail API for Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)

> It features the method [`Users.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) which allows you to
>   triage the messages by both labels and query simultaneously.

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
 Logger.log(Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {'labelIds': 'Label_1003148783259556236','q': 'subject:Pending' }));
}
```

Make sure you enable Gmail API from the Apps Script UI `Resources-> Advanced Google Services-> Gmail API`

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. I have tried all the methods. But, I am not where I need to change.@Tedinoz, I have checked the comment. But, I have already used theards. So, @Tedinoz or ziganotschka, any one could help me how to use apps script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not where I need to change"? What exactly is the problem?